# how to apply a check on below scenarios using if else conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, if-statement

I have a dataframe like this -[Please refer the dataframe as in the image shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIMth.png)

There are four columns('status','preferred_time','history','id'), need to check if all the columns have some values in it or not, in the history column ,its a nested list in some cases, so need to specially check nested list has all mandatory keys 'branch','rank','discharge_status','service_start',job_code','post_intention' have values in it, and add a column named "output" in the dataframe if all the columns have values then name that as "completed" else "pending" if blank or NaN or [{}] in any column or history column has any missing key value pair.

From the image , only the first row should be in completed state rest should fall in pending.

Please help me out in building better if else situation here in this scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Dict of above df image -

```
{'status': {0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: nan, 3: 'No', 4: 'No'},
 'preferred_time': {0: "['Morning', 'Midday', 'Afternoon']",
  1: [],
  2: "['Morning'] ",
  3: nan,
  4: "['Morning', 'Midday'] "},
 'history': {0: "[{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '1999-02-13', 'job_code': '09', 'post_intention': ['No']}]",
  1: "[{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '1999-02-13', 'job_code': '09', 'post_intention': ['No']}]",
  2: "[{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '1995-02-13', 'job_code': '09', 'post_intention': ['No']},{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E6', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '2015-02-13', 'job_code': '09'}]",
  3: nan,
  4: '[{}]'},
 'id': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}}
```

I tried below lines of code -
But I don't know how to check all the four columns in a single if statement -

```
for i in df.index:
    status = df['status'][i]
    preferred_time = df['preferred_time'][i]
    id = df['id'][i]
    history = df['history'][i]
    if status and preferred_time and id and status!='' and preferred_time!= '' and id!='':
        enroll_status = "completed"
    else:
        enroll_status = "pending"
    if history!= '' or str(history)!= '[{}]':
        for item in history:
            if 'branch' in item.keys() and'rank' in item.keys() and'discharge_status' in item.keys() and'service_start' in item.keys() and 'job_code' in item.keys() and 'post_intention' in item.keys():
                enroll_status = "completed"
            else:
                enroll_status = "pending"
```

Comment: It would be helpful if instead of giving an image, you could paste the result of `df.head().to_dict()` (where `df` is your dataframe).

Comment: @BenGrossmann https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476977/ben-grossmann, created a dict for the dataframe.

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this problem and where are you stuck? @deepu2711

Comment: @Vishnudev https://stackoverflow.com/users/5120049/vishnudev , added the line of codes I tried.

Comment: @deepu Is there a reason that the entries of your dataframe are strings rather than actual lists? Also, there's no need to include links to user profiles in your responses.

Comment: @deepu It's not clear what you mean by "so need to specially check nested list has all mandatory keys". Is it necessary that each dictionary within the array contains all mandatory keys, or do we merely require that each key appears in at least one of the dictionaries within the array? In my answer I assume you mean the first of these possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

def check_list(L):
    if not isinstance(L,list):
        return False
    return all(k in d for k in keys_req for d in L)

labels = np.array(["pending","completed"])
keys_req = ['branch','rank','discharge_status','service_start','job_code','post_intention']
d = {'status': {0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: nan, 3: 'No', 4: 'No'}, 'preferred_time': {0: "['Morning', 'Midday', 'Afternoon']", 1: nan, 2: "['Morning'] ", 3: nan, 4: "['Morning', 'Midday'] "}, 'history': {0: "[{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '1999-02-13', 'job_code': '09', 'post_intention': ['No']}]", 1: nan, 2: "[{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '1995-02-13', 'job_code': '09', 'post_intention': ['No']},{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E6', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '2015-02-13', 'job_code': '09'}]", 3: nan, 4: '[{}]'}, 'id': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['history_list'] = df['history'].apply(lambda x: eval(x) if isinstance(x,str) else x)
df['mandatory_keys'] = df['history_list'].apply(check_list)
df['no_nans'] = ~pd.isna(df).any(axis = 1)
df['output_tf'] = df['mandatory_keys'] & df['no_nans']
df['output'] = labels[df['output_tf'].to_numpy(dtype=int)]
```

Note that I corrected some typos from your dataframe in my copied version of the dictionary d (for example, `'rank:'E7'` was replaced with `'rank':'E7'`). The incremental columns added (history_list, mandatory_keys, no_nans, output_tf) are there to make understanding the process that I applied here easier; it is not actually necessary to add these to the dataframe if, for example, you want to use as little space as possible. The script above results in the following dataframe `df`:

```
  status                      preferred_time  \
0     No  ['Morning', 'Midday', 'Afternoon']   
1     No                                 NaN   
2    NaN                        ['Morning']    
3     No                                 NaN   
4     No              ['Morning', 'Midday']    

                                             history  id  \
0  [{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_stat...   1   
1                                                NaN   5   
2  [{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_stat...   2   
3                                                NaN   3   
4                                               [{}]   4   

                                        history_list  mandatory_keys  no_nans  \
0  [{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_stat...            True     True   
1                                                NaN           False    False   
2  [{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_stat...           False    False   
3                                                NaN           False    False   
4                                               [{}]           False     True   

   output_tf     output  
0       True  completed  
1      False    pending  
2      False    pending  
3      False    pending  
4      False    pending
```

Here's a more parsimonious version (which doesn't add the unnecessary columns or store the extra "labels" variable).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

def check_list(L):
    if not isinstance(L,list):
        return False
    return all(k in d for k in keys_req for d in L)

keys_req = ['branch','rank','discharge_status','service_start','job_code','post_intention']
d = {'status': {0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: nan, 3: 'No', 4: 'No'}, 'preferred_time': {0: "['Morning', 'Midday', 'Afternoon']", 1: nan, 2: "['Morning'] ", 3: nan, 4: "['Morning', 'Midday'] "}, 'history': {0: "[{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '1999-02-13', 'job_code': '09', 'post_intention': ['No']}]", 1: nan, 2: "[{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E7', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '1995-02-13', 'job_code': '09', 'post_intention': ['No']},{'branch': 'A', 'rank': 'E6', 'discharge_status': 'Honorable Discharge', 'service_start': '2015-02-13', 'job_code': '09'}]", 3: nan, 4: '[{}]'}, 'id': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}}    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['output'] = np.array(["pending","completed"])[
    (df['history'].apply(lambda x: eval(x) if isinstance(x,str) else x)
                  .apply(check_list)
     & ~pd.isna(df).any(axis = 1)
     ).to_numpy(dtype=int)]
```

---

A version that addresses your latest comment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
display(df)
df['output'] = np.array(["pending","completed"])[
    (df['history'].apply(lambda x: eval(x) if isinstance(x,str) else x)
                  .apply(check_list)
     & ~pd.isna(df).any(axis = 1)
     & (df['preferred_time']!="[]")
    ).to_numpy(dtype=int)]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476977/ben-grossmann , this solution worked perfectly, But I have a case in preferred time has empty [] list , its also showing output as completed , that should come as pending , as there is no value in it, how should I check it ? Please help. Also updated the dict of dataframe with another case in preferred_time column.

Comment: @deepu2711 Again, there is no need to link user profiles. Why did you start the comment with `stackoverflow.com/users/2476977/ben-grossmann`? Also, your updated dict had another `'rank:'E7'`, which I fixed. Finally, please be consistent with your datatypes: if you want the `preffered_time` entries to be strings of the form `"[___]"` that's fine, but that means that for an empty list, the entry should be `"[]"` rather than the empty list `[]`, which is what you have now

Comment: sorry for the profile tag, was not aware of tagging people on this platform.

Comment: @deepu2711 `@[username]`  is how you tag/ping a user. If the user would automatically get a notification about a comment, sometimes this command is omitted from the comment (which is what I suspect happened to your comments on my answer). It's also sufficient to write `@[first few letters of username]` if there are no other users with those starting letters. For example, `@Ben` would ping me and `@deepu` would ping you. Note that it is only possible to notify users in this way if they have already commented on (or edited) the post.